# Transforming definite integral with finite bounds using u-subs into improper integral is possible?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can i transforming this integral:
$$\int_0^1 e^{-xt}\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right) \Bbb dx\quad t>0$$

By setting :
$$x=-\frac{1}{u}\rightarrow u=-\frac 1x$$
$$x=0\rightarrow u=-\infty$$
$$x=1\rightarrow u=-1$$

My new integral becomes an improper integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{t/u}\ln(-(1+u))}{u^2} \Bbb du$$

Tried to check with Wolfram Alpha when $t=1$, $t=2$, and $t=3$ gave me the same result. But is this allowed in math since we treat it's an undefined expression. Can you explain please?

Comment: your initial integral is also improper, you are just converting between an integral where the function is ubounded to another where the integration interval is unbounded.

Comment: Sure, take $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$ with the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ $$\int_0^1 2du$$ as a simple example (but in reverse). A valid change of variables will never change the value of the integral. Singularities that only appear due to the peculiarities of a change of variable are called coordinate singularities - they don't actually exist or represent a true singularity. The origin in polar coordinates is another example of a coordinate singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 e^{-tx} \log \left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right) \, dx$$
Substitute $\frac{1-x}{x}=u\to x=\frac{1}{u+1},\;dx=-\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}$

$$I=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{u+1}} \log u}{(u+1)^2} \, du$$
The $u$ integral is almost as hard as the original, though.